# Many p,q-Sylow subgroups

Tags: finite-groups, gr.group-theory

It is a fact that the symmetric groups have as many 2-Sylow subgroups as possible.  More precisely, for all $n \geq 1$, the number of 2-Sylow subgroups in $S_n$ is exactly $n!/2^{\nu_2(n!)}$, which is the index of a 2-Sylow subgroup of $S_n$. This follows from (or, depending on which direction you're coming from, proves) the fact that one (equivalently, all) 2-Sylow subgroup is self normalizing.

It isn't too hard to show that given a prime $p$, there is a family of finite groups $(G_n)$ such that $\nu_p(|G_n|) \rightarrow \infty$ and all the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G_n$ are self-normalizing.

I want to generalize this to two primes in the obvious way, but I am encountering difficulty. The following would be a good start.

> Given distinct primes $p$, $q$, does there exist a finite group $G$ such that $pq \ \Big| \ |G|$ and all $p$-Sylow, all $q$-Sylow subgroups are self-normalizing?

Comment: The answer to your highlighted question is no: see Corollary 1.3 in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-04/S0002-9939-03-07161-2/home.html. (Found through a google search for "self-normalizing sylow p-subgroup")

Comment: Faisal, this is indeed the exact answer to my question!  Why don't you post it as an answer so I can confirm it?  Thanks!

Comment: Will do. I left it as a comment in case you wanted to reformulate your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is **no**: see Corollary 1.3 in

> Robert M. Guralnick; Gunter Malle; Gabriel Navarro, *[Self-normalizing Sylow subgroups](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-04/S0002-9939-03-07161-2/home.html)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **132** (2004), 973-979.